# How is a coordinate system called where values increase to the bottom instead to the top?

Tags: terminology, coordinate-systems

In some computer graphics libraries the coordinate system is almost like the "usual" cartesian coordinate system. The only difference is that the $y$ values increas to the bottom, not to the top.

Does this kind of coordinate system have a name?

Answer (score 1):

This is simply right-handed vs. left-handed (or right-chiral vs. left-chiral) orientation.

Comment: Judging from the image on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(physics) I think right- and left-handed is about the $x$ axis. But my question is about the $y$ axis.

Comment: @moose There are only two orientations. If we can use Wikipedia, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_%28vector_space%29

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke It's true that there are only two orientations, but there are four choices when specifying the directions in which values along the horizontal and vertical axes increase.

Comment: @Travis But they are identical up to rotation. And if we rotate axes by any angle $\alpha$ it does not mean that we have infinitely many choices.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Sure they are identical up to rotation / mirroring. But you should better get the rotation right when you implement a controller. It could make an important difference if an autonomous car sees something happen on the right side, tries to avoid collision and steers to the right. So "identical up to rotation / mirroring" is not enough for some contexts.